# angularJS $location.path with parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, location, angular-ui-router

In angular app I need to redirect to page to full url path with parameters.

For example

```
//get from cookie
var log_route = $cookies.get("hash_route"); //=>"/cart/activity?site_id=123&sec=foo"
$location.path(log_route);
```

the location worked just if no params available.

My problem that I don't know what url I get from the cookie and if params exists or not.

I can move to page by using the `$window.location`, but I want to know if I can move to full path with no refreshing the hole page.

(BTW I use angular ui router so if there is the an option of using the `$state` instead of `$loaction` with string full path it's better)

Answer (score 0):

do you try with absolute path ? like 'http://yourWebSite/cart/activity?site_id=123&sec=foo'
As the doc say, it is possible to pass parameter : 
[$location Doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location)

Comment: $location.path("http://localhost:3000/app/index#/cart/activity?site_id=127&events=Recovered%20Sale");
Does not work for me

Comment: $location redirect in a blank page with this url ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use url and not path

```
// given url http://example.com/#/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo
var url = $location.url();
// => "/some/path?foo=bar&baz=xoxo"
```

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$location